# postfix/postfix-script: fatal: mail system startup failed

Tags: debian, email, postfix

In a Digital Ocean droplet with Debian 10 (buster), trying to set up postfix + dovecot email server. Trying to do `postfix start`:

```
$ sudo postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: mail system startup failed
```

Status:

```
$ sudo postfix status 
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is not running
```

Reload:

```
$ sudo postfix reload
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running
```

Pemissions:

```
$ sudo postfix set-permissions
```

Restart:

```
$ sudo systemctl status postfix
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-04-15 02:36:43 UTC; 19s ago
  Process: 7465 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7465 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

abr 15 02:36:43 mail systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
abr 15 02:36:43 mail systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

re-try:

```
$ sudo postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: mail system startup failed
```

Comment: for past few years I have been running  https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver  which uses postfix inside a docker container ... it has scripts to define the baseline needs including TLS certs ... and its github issues are active and friendly ... besides its a gentle way to learn postfix ... otherwise to do any customizations  to the set of postfix configs will take weeks of trials and tribulations ... if not months ;-)

Comment: @ScottStensland, thanks for helping. I'm using external server right now. In a few weeks I'm gonna try this and let you know about results.